# Android issue with image size in gridview

Tags: android, android-xml, android-gridview

I am trying to create a grid layout of cards similar to what is used in google play like this

[image]

The layout i am using and the layout obtained are these:

For GridView:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#e5e5e5"
     >

    <GridView  
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="60dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"

    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

for GridItem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/bg_card"

>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:layout_below="@id/imgIcon"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The output that I get is this:

[image]

The image size that i am using is 356x500. (I do get a somewhat well sized grid on using 300x300)
The issues that i am facing are:

1. 1.As this image shows, the cards are too big with lots of white spaces around the image and the image does not fit like in the
   google play store. How do i make the card be propotional to the
   image. The amount of white space changes with change in image size.
2. The card is "stuck" to the left edge of the screen . How do i keep spacing between the edge of the screen and the card.

Please help me in rectifying this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Space are bacause you used

```
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
```

Also edit your

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     />
```

in gridview use 
android:stretchMode="none" instead of  android:stretchMode="columnWidth"

Comment: but isnt that for the space BETWEEN two cards? I changed it to 1dp but there is still lot of white space INSIDE every individual card around the image.  Thanks

Comment: I am still getting the same result. There is still a lot of white space around the image and changing the spacing only reduces the space between the cards

Comment: space are depend on you screen size and how many image will be in per row and image size

Comment: so i need to change the image that i am using in order to achieve the desired layout? Isnt there any way i can strech the image to fit the card?

Comment: try to use android:stretchMode="none" in gridview layout and all codes will be unchanged

Comment: no changing the strech mode also doesnt work instead, the grid item become rectangles with very large height and very small width which are aligned to the left of the screen leaving the rest as blank.?

Comment: have you changed android:stretchMode="none"

Comment: add android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Comment: any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Put android:scaleType="fitStart" inside your

Answer (score 0):

Use `imgIcon.setAdjustViewBounds(true);`
You can also do the same in the xml